# How do I import multiple PDF files and change their names using R

Tags: r, pdf, import, rename

I have a folder with +100 PDF files, each with a name. I also have csv file that have the matching name for the PDFs and another column with a numeric ID number. What I want to do is import all of them in R and add the numeric ID based in the matching name (from the files), and eventually export them with that new name.

I have a pretty good idea on how to do it with csv or txt files, but I have no clue what to do with PDFs. Could anyone give me a hand please.

Here my attempt of what to do...

```
# Required libraries
library(tm)

# Folder with csv file
setwd("/Users/Home/Desktop/Andrea")
wd <- getwd()
setwd(wd)

# Import CSV file
db <- read.csv("Lista de referencia.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
head(db)

# Folder with the PDF files
setwd("/Users/Home/Desktop/Andrea/Para renombrar")
wd1 <- getwd()
setwd(wd1)

# Import PDF files
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.pdf$")

DF <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(files)) {

  dat <- readPDF(files[i])

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the *content* of the PDFs?

Comment: No, just the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is just a matter of renaming the pdf files we don't actually have to read them in -- just use `file.rename`.

**1)** To keep the code below self-contained without actually using any files we have commented out the `file.rename` line.  You can either un-comment that line before running the code or else redirect the `cat` output to a file and then source that file into R.

```
# test inputs
db <- data.frame(id = 1:2, name = c("a.pdf", "b.pdf"))
files <- db$name

for(fn in files) {
   i <- match(fn, db$name, nomatch = 0)
   if (i > 0) {
     new_name <- sprintf("%s.%d.pdf", sub(".pdf$", "", fn), db$id[i])
     cat("file.rename('", fn, "', '", new_name, "')\n", sep = "")
     # file.rename(fn, new_name)
   } else warning(fn, " was not renamed as it was not found in db")
}
```

giving:

```
file.rename('a.pdf', 'a.1.pdf')
file.rename('b.pdf', 'b.2.pdf')
```

**2)** Alternately, we could use this vectorized approach:

```
not_found <- setdiff(files, db$name)
if (length(not_found) > 0) 
  warning("These files were not found in db:", toString(not_found))

found <- intersect(files, db$name)
new_names <- sprintf("%s.%d.pdf", sub(".pdf$", "", found), db$id[match(found, db$name)])
# file.rename(found, new_names)
```